# Everybody wants me, everybody owns me, everybody needs me!

Tags: riddle

> When you touch me I feel abused,
>
> but when you carry me around I feel amused.
>
> Why does that man wants me so bad?
>
> He even seems to be mad!
>
> You know, Donald Trump wants me as well!
>
> Oh no, I got confused. He won't win Nobel.
>
> I'll tell you the reason why, listen to me
>
> It's just the president wants me without E.T.!

What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> Wallet

Because

> A president wants it without E.T which is wallet - E.T = Wall, where Trump proposing a wall between US and Mexico, enjoy!